# Restservices call with params

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, web-services

I am working on an app written in java and angular. The request goes from angular with params and I need to read the params in the rest services. The angular piece is fixed (I cannot change it), but I can update the java code as needed.

My issue: I cannot read the params in my java services method. The value is always null.

angular code:

```
alert("params : "+JSON.stringify(params, null, 2));

return $http.get(url, {
    params: params
}).success(function (data) {
        // success criteria
    });
```

The params looks like this based on the alert statement:

```
 {
  "start": 0,
  "end": 100,
  "type": "asdf",
  "name": null,
  "values": [],
  "locs": [],
  "test1": "Val"
}
```

My java code looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("valuesList")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)

public String getValues(@RequestParam("type")String type) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("type ================"+type);

}
```

The type is null. I want to read all the values, but for now I am just using the type for testing. I also tried various @Consumes values, but nothing helps.

I think I need to change the @RequestParam, but not sure to what though. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Are you able to verify that the angular call is actually adding all those params on as request parameters via your browser's network tab or similar? At first glance it seems like this is just a mismatch between what the client sent vs what the server expected.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I was able to solve this, I had to update the RequestParam to QueryParam. I tested couple of others except QueryParam. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post the solution - I had to update the @RequestParam to @QueryParam. The updated method call is below

```
public String getValues(@QueryParam("type")String type) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("type ================"+type);

}
```

Comment: It worked because `@RequestParam` is Spring annotation and you are using JAX-RS so you need to annotate it with `@QueryParam`.

Comment: Thanks Amit. How do I find which way it is being used (meaning how do you say it is JAX-RS in this scenario). Thanks.

Comment: ‘@QueryParam’ is not spring annotation